# Удалить неиспользуемый загрузчик EFI

Tags: linux, debian

1. Установил LMDE 2, как вторую систему рядом с Windows.
2. Установил Debian 8.2 по верх LMDE 2.
3. Удалил директорию `/boot/efi/EFI/linuxmint`
4. После перезагрузки в списке Boot загрузчика отображается `linuxmint`

Как удалить неиспользуемый загрузчик EFI полностью, какие каталоги нужно проверить?

Comment: Попробовал обновить `GRUB`, но без результата. Что за файл?

Comment: Вы знаете, директория `/boot/efi/EFI` как раз содержала загрузчики Windows и Debian, по видимому есть еще одна директория.
Еще один момент, когда выбираешь загрузчик `linuxmint`, то загружается Windows.

Comment: А какое отношение имеет конфигурация `grub` к удаленному загрузчику `linuxmint`?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33155/discussion-between-vite-decorum-and-alexander-barakin).

Comment: Я не нахожу в файле конфигурации что-то связанное с `linuxmint`.

Comment: а что вы подразумевали под *Boot загрузчиком* в четвёртом пункте?

Comment: Загрузка через F12, и далее по списку...
По умолчанию, загружается Windows 10. Если нужно войти в Linux, только через F12.

Comment: Boot Manager BIOS

Comment: *Boot Manager BIOS* т.е., это относится к «прошитой» в железе микро-программе, но не к программе *grub*. и уж тем более к программе *linux*, которую загружает программа *grub*. // вот с этой микро-программой вам и надо «разбираться» — откуда она черпает информацию.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вывод списка EFI загрузчиков:

```
sudo efibootmgr
```

Команда удаления загрузчика по индексу, например:

```
sudo efibootmgr -b 5 -B
```

Источник: [How do I remove “Ubuntu” in the bios boot menu? (UEFI)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/63610/how-do-i-remove-ubuntu-in-the-bios-boot-menu-uefi)